# Codeigniter 3 Setting session pops MYSQL error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working with codeigniter for not a long time, but I encountered a really weird issue.

I'm trying to set a session called user_id after login process but for some reason I get a MYSQL error, even doe I do NOT use MYSQL as session storage.

There's the session config file.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

There shouldn't be any reason for CI to actually give me a MYSQL error when trying to set the session.

Comment: i think your problem is connected with autorization process but session

Comment: When I'm trying to create a default php session without codeigniter session class it works well..

Comment: comment line with creating session. What is about error in this case?

Comment: This is the error

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near SET last_activity = 1461574823, user_data = 'a:2:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\"' at line 1`

Comment: echo `$this->db->get_compiled_select()` before `get()`

Comment: This is the result :  `SELECT *`

Comment: And from where does mysql take `SET last_activity = ...` ?

Comment: well first of all  i'm not sure why MYSQL is involved in this since the session should be stored in file..

Comment: `SET last_activity` comes from your authorization process, which writes data about login in DB. Session is really nothing to do with. I've written you this from the start of our dialog

Comment: better read this first, https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find the answer... the issue was that by default the lastest Codeigniter version did not had `$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;` added in config.php file.